# When I deploy my rails app to heroku a foreign key disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

All the code that I'm showing below is the code that I have cloned from heroku.

I have this relationship in my app:

## Schema

```
  create_table "spots", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "id",        null: false
    t.integer "bid_cents", null: false
    t.integer "ask_cents", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "id",                                       null: false
    t.string   "type",                                     null: false
    t.text     "description",                              null: false
    t.decimal  "weight",                                   null: false
    t.string   "metal",                                    null: false
    t.string   "spot_id",                                  null: false
    t.integer  "elemetal_capital_premium_cents"
    t.integer  "goldtrex_markup_cents",                    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
    t.integer  "shopify_id",                     limit: 8, null: false
  end

add_index "products", ["spot_id"], name: "index_products_on_spot_id", using: :btree
```

## Extract from the models

### Extract from product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id

  belongs_to :spot

  before_create :shopify_create
  before_update :shopify_update
  ...
```

### Extract from spot

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id

  monetize :bid_cents
  monetize :ask_cents

  has_many :products
```

### Extract of inheritance from Product to ElemetalCapitalProduct and GoldtrexProduct

```
class ElemetalCapitalProduct < Product

  def self.available_products
    ElemetalCapital::Product.all.size
  end

class GoldtrexProduct < Product
  validates_presence_of :id, 
                        :description, 
                        :weight, 
                        :metal, 
                        :spot_id,
                        :goldtrex_markup_cents
```

## Methods that I'm trying to use

```
def self.update_products!
    ec_products = ElemetalCapital::Product.all
    transaction do
      ec_products.each do |ec_product|
        product = ElemetalCapitalProduct.where(id: ec_product.id).first_or_initialize
        product.spot_id = ec_product.spot
        product.goldtrex_markup = 25
        product.description = ec_product.description
        product.metal = ec_product.metal
        product.weight = ec_product.weight
        product.elemetal_capital_premium = ec_product.premiumBuy
        product.save!
      end
    end
```

In the controller:

```
  def master_update
    ElemetalCapitalProduct.update_products!
    redirect_to elemetal_capital_products_path
  end
```

## Problem

If I run that method in my local machine that works. However, when I deploy to heroku, and I try to use that method I got this error:

```
Started GET "/elemetal_capital_products/elemetal_capital_api_dashboard" for 101.176.220.53 at 2015-07-22 15:11:55 +0000
2015-07-22T15:11:55.383259+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-07-22T15:11:55.380497+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ElemetalCapitalProductsController#elemetal_capital_api_dashboard as HTML
2015-07-22T15:11:55.386042+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.erb (0.1ms)
2015-07-22T15:11:55.900630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/elemetal_capital_products/elemetal_capital_api_dashboard" host=goldtrex.herokuapp.com request_id=a6b622f6-aa23-4a77-817f-deb3d236b7eb fwd="101.176.220.53" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=524ms status=200 bytes=5498
2015-07-22T15:11:55.886397+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered elemetal_capital_products/elemetal_capital_api_dashboard.html.erb within layouts/application (501.3ms)
2015-07-22T15:11:55.888365+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 508ms (Views: 504.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2015-07-22T15:11:57.753099+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/elemetal_capital_products/master_update" for 101.176.220.53 at 2015-07-22 15:11:57 +0000
2015-07-22T15:11:57.926609+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.9ms)  BEGIN
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944657+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-22T15:11:57.942913+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.0ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944661+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `spot_id=' for #<ElemetalCapitalProduct:0x007f00909740b8>):
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944664+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/product.rb:95:in `each'
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944663+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/product.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in update_products!'
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944665+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/product.rb:95:in `block in update_products!'
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944667+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/product.rb:94:in `update_products!'
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944668+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/elemetal_capital_products_controller.rb:34:in `master_update'
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-22T15:11:57.944671+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-22T15:11:57.756503+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ElemetalCapitalProductsController#master_update as HTML
2015-07-22T15:11:57.756599+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"R8o+PLuoFdbHUttiEadQ1msEhOXt0TYZQz/bF6378zl2RdHVMePsYXH7fTPB5P///zSaKNWgrLOZSIN17D94eA=="}
2015-07-22T15:11:57.760060+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-07-22T15:11:57.933116+00:00 app[web.1]:   ElemetalCapitalProduct Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."type" IN ('ElemetalCapitalProduct') AND "products"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "SBAR10-OPM"]]
2015-07-22T15:11:57.943605+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 187ms
2015-07-22T15:11:57.951593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/elemetal_capital_products/master_update" host=goldtrex.herokuapp.com request_id=075d778d-acfb-4438-9f0d-a59b5f409a16 fwd="101.176.220.53" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=197ms status=500 bytes=1741
```

- I have run the migrations on the production app and all of them are up.

## Something strange

If I have to my rails console in heroku, and I type Product to see the attributes I can't see the spot_id

```
Product
=> Product(id: string, type: string, description: text, weight: decimal, metal: string, elemetal_capital_premium_cents: integer, goldtrex_markup_cents: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, shopify_id: integer)
```

But if I go to my local machine, I can see the spot_id:

```
[3] pry(main)> Product
=> Product(id: string, type: string, description: text, weight: decimal, metal: string, spot_id: string, elemetal_capital_premium_cents: integer, goldtrex_markup_cents: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, shopify_id: integer)
```

***Could someone help me with this problem?***, I compare the heroku code with my master branch, and they are the same. I'm thinking about running a migration to add spot_id, but it won't make sense because in the schema that relationship exists, however in the model apparently it doesn't exist.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to run a migration on heroku.  `rake db:migrate`

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: I ran the migrations, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku not run migration when you deploy your code you have to run migration right after you push code:

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and that is explain why you can't see the new column spot_id in you Product model.

Comment: On my question I clarify that I have run all the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I clone my heroku app with the command below:

```
% heroku git:clone -a the-app
```

After comparing my Heroku repo with the local repo I didn't find any difference in the code. Everything was the same, so I decided to reset my database.

```
 % heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

The I run the migrations, and finally the spot_id appeared, and I can update the products.